# Setting bg color with jQuery doesn't override existing one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that I use jQuery to color even and odd rows mainly because I want the user to chose which color he wants from few selections in form

But when I setup `bgcolor` of a table in css, the jQuery script won't work.

Below is the code to change the colors (jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sh7cgaz4/)

It stops working when adding to the css, eg:

```
table,th,td {
    background-color: red; 
}
```

here is the fiddle when it stops working: https://jsfiddle.net/8g7wn0ov/

```
$(function() {
    var colors = [{
    display: "jasny żółty",
    value: "ffffcc"        
}, {
    display: "jasny niebieski",
    value: "ccffff"
}, {
    display: "jasny zielony",
    value: "ccffcc"
}, {
    display: "szary",
    value: "cccccc"
}, {
    display: "biały",
    value: "ffffff"
}];
    
var options = ['<option value="">wybierz kolor</option>'];
    
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(colors[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(colors[i].display);
    options.push('</option>');       
}
    
$('#koloryparzyste').html(options.join('')).change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val){
            $('.parzyste').css('backgroundColor', '#' + val);
        }
    });
var options = ['<option value="">wybierz kolor</option>'];
    
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(colors[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(colors[i].display);
    options.push('</option>');       
}
    
$('#kolorynieparzyste').html(options.join('')).change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val) {
       $('.nieparzyste').css('backgroundColor', '#' + val);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work fine.   Can you describe the problem other than "doesn't work"?

Comment: like i said in the post yeah fidlle works fine until you type inside the css part background-color: #1F272B; or any other color of course than it stops working

Comment: You mean if you add some css to the css panel in the fiddle?  Please add that so it demonstrates the issue.  Otherwise it's just a *guess* as to what you're doing extra (to what's in the question) as that's where the issue is.

Comment: Works fine when I do it, *guessing* how you've added your css.  https://jsfiddle.net/xas6Lpyt/    Your jquery adds css to the `tr` - so if you add .css to the td it will, of course, override the tr as the td is "on top of" the tr.  Alternatively your jquery could add to the td:  `$('.nieparzyste td').css`  https://jsfiddle.net/xas6Lpyt/1/

Comment: yeah that was the problem when adding to td it stopped working thanks a lot now it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the css background colour on the `table,th,td` but in your javascript, you're only updating the `tr` (`.nieparzyste` / `.parzyste` which is a class on the `tr`).

As a `td` sits inside or "on top" of a `tr` the `td` colour overrides the `tr` colour.

You can fix this by setting the "default" (in the css) colour only on the `tr`, or by changing the jquery to also update the `td`.

Snippet using `tr` colour:

```js
$(function() {
  var colors = [{
    display: "jasny żółty",
    value: "ffffcc"
  }, {
    display: "jasny niebieski",
    value: "ccffff"
  }, {
    display: "jasny zielony",
    value: "ccffcc"
  }, {
    display: "szary",
    value: "cccccc"
  }, {
    display: "biały",
    value: "ffffff"
  }];

  var options = ['<option value="">wybierz kolor</option>'];

  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(colors[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(colors[i].display);
    options.push('</option>');
  }

  $('#koloryparzyste').html(options.join('')).change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      $('.parzyste').css('backgroundColor', '#' + val);
    }

  });
  var options = ['<option value="">wybierz kolor</option>'];

  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(colors[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(colors[i].display);
    options.push('</option>');
  }

  $('#kolorynieparzyste').html(options.join('')).change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      $('.nieparzyste').css('backgroundColor', '#' + val);
    }

  });


});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="prawy">
  <table id="kolorwa">
    <tr class="parzyste">
      <th>Lp.</th>
      <th>Imię</th>
      <th>Nazwisko</th>
      <th>Stanowisko</th>
      <th>Data zatrudnienia</th>
      <th>Ilość dni urlopowych</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nieparzyste">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Barbar</td>
      <td>Sznuk</td>
      <td>Dział Hr</td>
      <td>11.06.2002</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parzyste">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Tomasz</td>
      <td>Kopyra</td>
      <td>Pracwnik Produkcji</td>
      <td>11.06.2005</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nieparzyste">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Tomasz</td>
      <td>Bukowski</td>
      <td>Pracwnik Produkcji</td>
      <td>02.01.2007</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parzyste">
      <td>4 </td>
      <td>Janusz</td>
      <td>Tracz</td>
      <td>Kierownik</td>
      <td>21.06.2007</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nieparzyste">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Grzegorz</td>
      <td>Kowalski</td>
      <td>Dyrektor</td>
      <td>29.09.1999</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <form name="koloryparzyste">Tu zmienisz kolory parzyste<br>
    <select id="koloryparzyste"></select>
  </form>
  <form name="kolorynieparzyste">Tu zmienisz kolory nieparzyste<br>
    <select id="kolorynieparzyste"></select>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `background-color` instead of `backgroundColor`

```
$('.nieparzyste').css('background-color', '#' + val);
```

Comment: You're thinking of css,  names in camel case work fine in jquery, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/jo0skau4/